# In CiviMember, can one set a rule where expired members, when renewing, are assigned probation status

Tags: civimember, status

We have assigned status rules in Civi member, which flow as follows:
Member joins = Probation
After 6 months = Current

In next year, until end of March if hasn't renewed = Grace-Voting
If renews = Current

After March, if hasn't renewed = Grace Non-Voting
If renews = Current

If Grace Non-Voting for full year = Expired

If expired and renews = Current

Our membership rules state that where members renew after their membership has expired they must serve the 6 month probationary period. Hence rule should be:

If expired and renews = probationary

Is it possible to set this status rule in CiviMember?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Lawrence: One thought would be to take the approach that if an expired member signs up again, that rather than renewing the original membership, it creates a brand new one - in which case i assume your existing Probation process would work fine.

I don't recall if there is an Extension or just a setting to change CiviMember to always create a new membership but i know it has been done as some Ors prefer that.

If you think that could work for you, I or someone else can probably post a link to it if providing you with the idea is not enough to help you find it yourself.

UPDATE

Also note that eg for Drupal there is a Member Role Synch module that lets you specify what User Roles are given/removed based on the civi membership type and status

Comment: FYI - are you aware of https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/ as another way of getting support

Comment: Thanks for the insight petednz, appreciate you coming back to us on this. I'll have a look and see if I can work it out.

Comment: So, I've done a little bit of digging and have a few ideas about what needs to be done: At the moment all contacts that are in our database including expired members have a Civi User ID. If expired members did not have a Civi User ID I wonder if expired members re-joining the party would be allocated a new contact record and user ID, i.e. a fresh membership account. To do this I imagine in the Administer menu there must be a way to configure expired 'records' (members) to lose User/Member access to Civi. Does this sound logical?

Comment: "civi user id" isn't a phrase i would use. The CMS, WP or Drupal, creates the users. Some civi Contact records will have a 'user record' associated with it via the uf_match table. That said, trying to answer, if a Civi 'contact' has a 'user' record, and the civi contact has a membership that expires (hence a member id) then I would not expect a new civi 'contact' nor cms 'user' to be created. if that is happening maybe check your dedupe rules. also perhaps open this as a new question

Comment: added comment re user role sync in drupal - not sure if WP has something similar